# RANDEVU - Rust crate implementing a simple algorithm I invented

Tags: algorithm, datetime, rust, library, time

I've created a simple algorithm which I've implemented in Rust and published it as a crate on crates.io.
https://crates.io/crates/randevu

While I do think my code is pretty clean and idiomatic, I would like to know if there are any suggestions on how to improve it further, including tests and documentation. I have some ideas like allowing the user to pass a chrono date/time to the function instead of the function only taking dates as a string. Or making a version that accepts blake3 hashes of object and date (so they can be calculated only once for instances where the function is called many times for a certain object or date).

For those interested in the function and idea behind the algorithm itself, I've tried to explain it the best I can in the README.md (though it might not be relevant for code review).

````
//! The official Rust implementation of the [RANDEVU](https://github.com/TypicalHog/randevu) algorithm
//!
//! # Example
//! ```rust
//! use randevu::{rdv, utc_date_with_offset};
//!
//! fn main() {
//!     let object = "THE_SIMPSONS";
//!     let date = utc_date_with_offset(0);
//!     let rdv = rdv(object, &date);
//!
//!     println!("Object {} has RDV{} today", object, rdv);
//! }
//! ```

use blake3;
use chrono::{TimeDelta, Utc};

/// Returns current UTC DATE `String` in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD), with an OFFSET `i64` in days
pub fn utc_date_with_offset(offset: i64) -> String {
    (Utc::now() + TimeDelta::days(offset))
        .format("%Y-%m-%d")
        .to_string()
}

/// Returns RDV level `u32` for an OBJECT `&str` on a specific DATE `&str`
///
/// **RDV = number of leading zero bits in blake3(blake3(OBJECT) || blake3(DATE))**
pub fn rdv(object: &str, date: &str) -> u32 {
    let mut hasher = blake3::Hasher::new();
    hasher.update(blake3::hash(object.as_bytes()).as_bytes());
    hasher.update(blake3::hash(date.as_bytes()).as_bytes());
    let final_hash = hasher.finalize();

    let mut rdv = 0;
    for &byte in final_hash.as_bytes() {
        rdv += byte.leading_zeros();

        if byte != 0 {
            break;
        }
    }

    rdv
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_rdv_1() {
        assert_eq!(rdv("NO_BOILERPLATE", "2024-01-26"), 11);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_rdv_2() {
        assert_eq!(rdv("SHREK_2001", "2024-01-26"), 8);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_rdv_3() {
        assert_eq!(rdv("RANDEVU", "2024-01-26"), 1);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_rdv_4() {
        assert_eq!(rdv("RUST", "2024-01-26"), 0);
    }
}
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Naming

The function `rdv` has a name, that I'd never remember. It's described as *number of leading zero bits*, but it is never explained where the presumable abbreviation originates from.

`offset: i64` is passed to `TimeDelta::days`. So you should either explain that those are days in the docstring or rename the variable to `days`, so that the user knows what it does.

Aside from `object` being a non-descriptive name in general, `object: &str` is not generic over some type `T`. It always will be a `&str`. Since something called an *RDV level* is being calculated from it, maybe call it `target` or so. I really don't know since I cannot make sense of `rdv()` at all.

## Get your types early

`rdv()` should receive `date` as an appropriate object, not as a string slice. The serialization should be done internally. With the current implementation one can pass in an arbitrary string, that may not meet the function's expectations of a valid date.

E.g. what would you expect `x` to be in `assert_eq!(rdv("NO_BOILERPLATE", "Hello world"), x);`?

If you want to make `rdv()` really generic, as claimed in the README, you could rewrite it to `rdv<T: ToString>(target: T, ...)...`.

## Documentation

The contents of the project's README file are misleading.

1. The algorithms provided are not generic, as noted above.
2. Nothing is being done on a daily basis - there is no timed automation whatsoever in the code. It just exhibits some date serialization and a spurious hash function.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer!

The function is named rdv, which is short for RANDEVU (name of the algorithm).
You can think of it the same way as ETA stands for "estimated time of arrival" or BCE which stands for "before common era". I guess I should explain that better in the README.md file.
The values generated by the algorithm are commonly prefixed with RDV when one is referring to them and using them for the intended usecases.
If an object has a value 5 on a given day, the convention is to refer to it as RDV5.
Example usage: "Hey Mike, XONOTIC has RDV5 today, wanna play?"

Comment: I do explain the offset is in days in the docstring:  

/// Returns current UTC DATE `String` in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD), with an OFFSET `i64` in days  

I see how my use of the word generic can be confused with the type being generic.
The object is ALWAYS a string, but that string can represent ANY object (such as a movie, game, person, video, book, place, post, task etc.)
So I call it generic since the algorithm can be applied to ANYTHING that can be represented with a string as opposed to just tasks or meetings etc.
I do need to improve the README and explain stuff better.

Comment: The rdv function accepts a string and not a date because it is assumed the date will be stored in a file or somewhere else as a string, so it would have to be converted back to date and then back to string again before it is hashed.
I guess I should add a check which would reject invalid dates and maybe allow users to either pass the date as a string or a date object itself to the function.

Comment: "Nothing is being done on a daily basis - there is no timed automation whatsoever in the code. It just exhibits some date serialization and a spurious hash function."  

It's up to the user to decide how to use and implement the rdv function. They can run it once every day to calculate the RDV value for a single object they have, or many different objects. They can calculate the values for future dates, or past dates.
They can use the function in a loop and keep calculating the RDV values for an object until they find the date where the value returned by the function is a specific value etc

Comment: `"so it would have to be converted back to date and then back to string again before it is hashed"` <- which is perfectly fine, because `rdv` will be cleaner and easier to maintain (and use) as a result. If you change the type of `rdv`'s `date` parameter to be a date object, you won't need to write validation logic in the body of `rdv`, and the return type can remain as it is, `u32`. If you keep `date` as a string and add validation logic, you'll need to change the return type to a `Result` or allow `rdv` to panic, both which are not as clean alternatives compared to just using a date object.

Comment: @TypicalHog Relevant article: [Parse, don’t validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/)

Comment: @Setris Good suggestions! Thank you!